# UITextView content scrolls outside its bounds (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I am using `displayData = UITextView()` and `displayData.isScrollEnabled = true` to display some data in a scrollable view.

The data should be entirely contained within the textview.

Scrolling works as expected, except that the data extends below the textView's lower bound (but not above the upper bound), and appears on top of other views:

[image]

I have played around with all of the following without success:

```
displayData.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero    
displayData.clipsToBounds = true
super.clipsToBounds = true
displayData.layer.masksToBounds = true
displayData.scrollRectToVisible(displayData.bounds, animated: true)
```

How do I prevent the content from scrolling outside the textView?

Comment: are your constraints correct? looks like potentially the text view has a frame larger than the white background

Comment: That was my thought, but I'm doing it programmatically so I'm not sure. I have a UIView in IB (with fixed constraints.  That UIView may be assigned any of several classes.  In this case, the UITextView was added with `self.addSubview(displayData)`.

Comment: it's quite easy to check the frame of the text view at runtime using debug view hierarchy or print statements.

Comment: Am I doing the right thing with this: `debugPrint("superview: \(superview!.bounds.height), displayData: \(displayData.bounds.height)")`?  If so, the heights are equal.

Comment: not necessarily.. you need to place the print statements after the view has appeared on screen e.g viewDidAppear

Comment: also i've not been able to reproduce this. could you try removing the `scrollRectToVisible` and see if that helps?

Comment: The `scrollRectToVisible` was a recent attempt that did not seem to have any effect.

Comment: I created a global variable, assigned `displayData.bounds.height` to it, then printed it from the viewController in viewDidAppear.  If that is correct, then no, the  frame is not larger than the view.

Comment: Your first response was correct!  I had set the height of the UIView in which `displayData` textView resides equal to `view.frame.height` rather than its container height.  I am an idiot...